# why Query DateTime data as string in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

in my collection, i see StartTime is DateTime type, but when I the following code, VS identifies value as string

```
var ele = item13.GetElement("StartTime"); 
Response.Write(ele.Name.GetType().ToString() + ": " + eleValue + "<BR/>");
```

the result is,

```
System.String: 2017-04-17T01:42:34Z
```

my question is, why is it considered as System.String instead of DateTime while my collection stored value as DateTime?

Comment: I think `ele.Name.GetType()` returns `String` from the `Name` property type instead of `DateTime`, try with `ele.GetType().ToString()`.

Comment: Hi @TetsuyaYamamoto,
`ele` is `BSON Element` object.
your suggest is not working for my case.
What I'm trying to do is  finding the Type of Column.
So far, I only have single [<key>,<value>] for each Document.